# kml to shapefile conversion in PyQGIS

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, convert, kml

How to convert kml to shapefile using python code? I'm using the code below but it's not properly coverting:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("D:\KML-Images\dp0844061p.kml", "line", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(vlayer)

_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat\
(_vlayer,"hoppla.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")

_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer,r"D:\KML-Images\dp0844061p.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")

_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer,r"D:\KML-Images\ShapeFile\dp0844061p.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a couple of issues:

1. You need to escape your path if you're using single backslashes (use a double backslash at the end of your desired directory; or use single forward slashes; or add the `r` prefix before your path).
2. Your second `_writer` command calls `_vlayer` which hasn't been defined (this command actually works).

---

So you could use the following:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("D:/KML-Images/dp0844061p.kml", "line", "ogr")

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, "D:/KML-Images/dp0844061p.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inputPath=select kml Available Path+ "\\" 
inputPath = inputPath +  filename
#print inputPath
outputPath=select converted shape file storage Available Path + "\\" +  filename +".shp"
outputPath=self.FolderOutputPath +"\ Polygon_Shape\\" +  filename+".shp"

outputPath = outputPath.replace("\\","//")
print inputPath
print outputPath
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(inputPath, filename+"_line", "ogr")

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer,outputPath ,"utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(vlayer)
```